# Spring UML referenced sub-machine not working

Tags: uml, spring-statemachine

Is there a working example for the Spring UML sub-machine reference shown in Section 31.16 of 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/

In my case, it seems as if the `sub statemachine` that is referenced is never entered.

Comment: Provide some code please to show what you are trying.

Comment: Hello,  I was trying to do exactly what they did in the documentation and I finally found some tests that were added a few months ago: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/tree/master/spring-statemachine-uml/src/test     I will try to upgrade to the latest build snapshot (2.0.0)  and see if this doesn't solve the problem I am having using the latest release (1.2.1).

Comment: if you run in to trouble update your question with some of what you have tried. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, you need to show what you're trying to do. I'd stay away from master branch as that's for development, 1.2.x serie is main stable branch until 2.0.0 is out later this year.

Comment: Hi Janne. Thanks for your answer. Yes working with the Master was probably not a good idea. After double checking, Release 1.2.2 also has the simple-submachineref test and it works properly of course. I think the problems that I have been having are related to Papyrus that doesn't update the XML file properly when deleting transitions, amongst other things. I only just started to use the Spring Test recently, and it has really been a big help.  I will try and figure out exactly what the problem is with Papyrus, but I suspect that this is not a Spring issue...

Comment: As a follow up, I updated to the latest version of Papyrus and Neon.2 and am using the same dependencies as the examples from Spring Statemachine 1.2.2.Release and everything is working very well. I have not been able to reproduce the problems I had.

Comment: I originally noticed same issues and I added some counter measures to skip some xml which looks to be garbage left by papyrus. It's little difficult case to handle as you don't know if xml is actually broken or if something was just left behind.